# Вопрос про неинициализированные переменные

Tags: c, переменные, c++

Здравствуйте. Есть такой вопрос: При обьявлении переменных и последующей их не инициализации при обращении к ним программа "вылетает". Почему? Какая программе разница, что в этих переменных находилось? Откуда программа знает, что переменные не были проинициализированны? Это сделано специально для чего-то, для чего и как отслеживает компьютер непроинициализированные переменые?
Спасибо.

Comment: - Вы, насколько я помню, разрабатываете с помощью Visual Studio, в которой применяется [механизм Runtime Error Check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx), конкретно — `/RTCu,` диагностирующий обращения к [неинициализированным переменным.](http://goo.gl/qqeC3M)

- Это сделано для того, что предотвратить ошибки, допущенные по невнимательности — то есть, скажем, подразумевалось, что переменная будет обнулена, но вы забыли дописать `'= 0'`. Ситуацию, когда кому-то потребовалось получить значение неинициализированной переменной, на практике же представить сложно.

Comment: думаю, будет интересно почитать похожий вопрос - [зачем обнулять переменные](http://hashcode.ru/questions/155912/c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=170022#170022)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Программе-то всё равно, не всё равно компилятору. Он имеет право считать, что переменная инициализирована, потому что обращение к неинициализированной переменной является undefined behaviour. Поэтому могут произойти самые непредсказуемые последствия.

Пример:

```
time_t rawtime = time(0);
struct tm* now = localtime(&rawtime); // получили текущую дату

bool timeBomb;    
if (now->tm_mday == 13 && now->tm_wday == 5) // пятница, 13-ое?
    timeBomb = true;

// ...
if (timeBomb)
{
    // бабах!
```

Смотрите, что может произойти. Компилятор проверяет, какое значение имеет переменная `timeBomb`. Если условие первого `if`'а выполнилось, значение `timeBomb` определено и равно `true`. Если нет, переменная `timeBomb` не инициализирована. По стандарту при обращении к неинициализированной переменной имеет право произойти всё, что угодно, поэтому компилятор **имеет право** не рассматривать этот случай вовсе! Итак, в единственном важном случае переменная `timeBomb` инициализирована значением `true`, а значит, компилятор имеет право воспринимать этот код так:

```
bool timeBomb;    
timeBomb = true;

if (timeBomb)
{
    // бабах!
```

то есть просто

```
bool timeBomb = true;

// бабах!
```

Неприятная ситуация, правда?

Итак: обращение к неинициализированным переменным может привести к различным сортам неприятностей (из которых креш программы — самая маленькая неприятность), причём не обязательно в точке, в которой произошло такое обращение.

---

«Имеет право» — не значит «обязан». Компилятор может производить data-flow analysis, а может и не производить. При обращении к неинициализированной переменной (а также любом другом undefined behaviour) вы даёте компилятору право поступать как ему вздумается. Компилятор может, в качестве «одолжения», вставлять проверки обращения к неинициализированным переменным, чтобы предохранить более серьёзные проблемы, но обычно эти проверки отключаются при компиляции в режиме максимальной оптимизации (Release mode для MSVC).