# Почему обязательна инициализация локальных переменных

Tags: c++, инициализация, локальные-переменные

Насколько я знаю локальные переменные по умолчанию инициализируются каким-либо мусором со стека, например тем что лежало по этому адресу ранее, так ли это? Следующий вопрос заключается вот в чем, если они все таки инициализируются какими-либо значениями, то почему компилятор msvc++ выбивает ошибку, про использование неинициализированной памяти. Почему так, если компилятор при компиляции должен только расставлять смещения и на значения переменных по идее не должен обращать внимание.

Comment: 1) Если вы не пытаетесь прочитать значение неинициализированной переменной, то и инициализировать её не обязательно. 2) `локальные переменные по умолчанию инициализируются каким-либо мусором со стека` Нет. Неинициализированная переменная находится в особом состоянии. Считается, что она хранит [_indeterminate value_](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.indet#1). За несколькими редкими исключениями, любые попытки прочитать значение такой переменной приводят к **неопределённому поведению**. Может произойти что угодно: прочитается мусор со стека, или всегда будет читаться ноль, или программа упадёт.

Comment: В этом и состоит суть неопределённого поведения. Любые гарантии стандарта языка снимаются, поведение программы ни как не специфицируется. 3) Неинициализированные переменные настолько распространённая ошибка, что у msvc++ даже есть спец. опции, используя которые, можно попросить его добавлять проверки на обращение к неинициализированным переменным. См.: [/RTC](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019). 4) [Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/245369).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Насколько я знаю локальные переменные по умолчанию инициализируются каким-либо мусором со стека, например тем что лежало по этому адресу ранее, так ли это?

нет, они не "инициализируются мусором", просто так складывается, что там оказывается такое значение.

> Следующий вопрос заключается вот в чем, если они все таки инициализируются какими-либо значениями, то почему компилятор msvc++ выбивает ошибку, про использование неинициализированной памяти.

нет, не инициализируется и Ваша программа стает "неопределенной". То есть, ее поведение зависит от факторов, которые не известны программе. Если Ваша программа считает что то (а что ей ещё делать?) и она основывается на не инициализированных переменных, то ее результат может быть в принципе любой. А значит компилятор (в теории) может выбрать один с  возможных вариантов и завершить на том.

Представьте, что Вы считаете сумму ряда, но вот переменную для суммирования Вы не инициализировали. Так как ее значение в теории может быть любое с возможных, то добавляя любое число, ответ все равно может быть любой. А значит компилятор может просто вывести 0 или 100 и он будет абсолютно прав. Именно поэтому компилятор и ругается.

> Почему так, если компилятор при компиляции должен только расставлять смещения и на значения переменных по идее не должен обращать внимание.

компилятор может ещё делать чудо оптимизации. Например, clang умеет считать в на этапе компиляции суммы ряда и сокращать до известной школьной формулы.

И как тут не вспомнить мою любимую шутку, которую найдете в другом моем ответе [Зачем нужно обнуление переменных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/155912/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/170022#170022)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня есть небольшой вопрос не совсем по теме. Может ли быть такое, что в ячейке оперативной памяти не будет абсолютно ничего (ни значения, ни каких то остатков от работы программы) , просто пустота

Comment: пустоты не может быть. байт это обычно 8 бит, int - это обычно 32, но бывает и 16, и 64. И один бит это  либо 1 либо 0. Чего то другого там не может быть, потому что это непонятно как измерить.